# Laravel send password reset link to a separate authentication guard

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In Laravel 5.4, is there a way to send the password reset link to a separate authentication guard instead of the default one. I am using the default `PasswordResetController` which does the job in this way

```
 public function company(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);
        $response = Password::sendResetLink([
            'email' => $request->email
        ]);

        //overridden if condition 
        if($response == "passwords.sent")
        {
        return back()->with('message','Password reset link has been sent, please check your email');
        }

        return back()->with('message', 'No such email address in our records, try again');
    }
```

The `sendResetLink()` method checks and sends the reset link to the default guard, but I am defining a new guard in `auth.php` called `web`

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'companies',
        ],
```

`sendResetLink` method is like this

```
  public function sendResetLink(array $credentials)
    {
        // First we will check to see if we found a user at the given credentials and
        // if we did not we will redirect back to this current URI with a piece of
        // "flash" data in the session to indicate to the developers the errors.
        $user = $this->getUser($credentials);

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return static::INVALID_USER;
        }
```

Any way for this method to check in a separate table or use a separate auth guard?

Comment: Can you explain your situation and what do you really want to do without that code you have introduced, because I suppose you do something wrong and people can't understand you right in order to help with this?

Answer (score 14):

Here is my method of how to **send password reset link to a guard** which is a part of multi-auth system.

I am going to assume you have properly set your new guard in `config/auth.php`
which may look like below code:

I use the  word **admin**  for the new guard's name for better understanding.

```
'guards' => [

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
]

'providers' => [

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
]


 'passwords' => [

    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 15,
    ],
]
```

You will have to create new controllers(`AdminForgotPasswordController` and `AdminResetPasswordController`) for your new guard

They both use the `Password` facade and `AdminResetPasswordController` uses `Auth` facade as well.

Modify the construct function according to your new guard.
So add this to both controllers, because we have specific type of guest users.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin');
}
```

Now we need to tell `AdminResetPasswordController` to use the proper guard for authenticating.

So add this method to the controller

```
protected function guard()
{
  return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

Now add this piece of code to both controllers.

```
protected function broker()
{
  return Password::broker('admins'); //set password broker name according to guard which you have set in config/auth.php
}
```

**Notice:** It's not the only step for implementing *password reset for guard* you will have to take other steps like creating new routes, notifications, forms and corresponding views.

Comment: How do you use it with `Password::sendResetLink` in a route?

Comment: ```Password::broker('broker-name')->sendResetLink```. Password broker name is from "resetting password" section of ```config/auth,php``` file.

Answer (score 7):

In your auth.php configuration file, you may configure multiple "guards", which may be used to define authentication behavior for multiple user tables. You can customize the included  `ResetPasswordController` to use the guard of your choice by overriding the guard method on the controller. This method should return a guard instance:

```
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('guard-name');
}
```

The magic lies, in using the `broker` - the PasswordBroker for your custom guard. But, you make sure to set up multiple password brokers in your auth.php configuration file.

```
protected function broker()
{

    return Password::broker('name');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way could be

```
 $response = Password::broker('guard-name')->sendResetLink([
        'email' => $request->email
    ]);
```

also don't miss reset function

```
$response = Password::broker('guard-name')->reset([
        'email' => $request->email
    ],function(){// save changes})
```